# Programmatically launch iOS Safari and do default search?

Tags: ios, url, search, safari

How do you programmatically launch iOS Safari, and have it do a search with the user's selected search engine?

Versus using openURL with http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22search+for+this%22

Would like to respect the user's settings if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString * urlString = @"x-web-search://?keyword";
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]) {
    if (iOS10) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    }
}
```